# Is there a way to set the alpha channel of the GUI in a HTA to get it transparent?

Tags: css, hta

Like `@Teemu` said I putted the `<!DOCTYPE html>` ant the  `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">`. Now it work with a strange behavior the GUI is not transparent but the color is clearer. So setting the Alpha channell act like reducing the value of the `RGB` color and not setting the transparency of the GUI.

Is there a way to have the main GUI transparent ?

The HTA GUI :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">
    <title>Test</title>

    <HTA:APPLICATION
    APPLICATIONNAME="Test"
    ID="RestoreHta"
    VERSION="1.0"
    BORDER="dialog"
    BORDERSTYLE="complex"
    INNERBORDER="no"
    SCROLL="no"
    CONTEXTMENU="no"/>

<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">

Sub Window_Onload
self.ResizeTo 300,300
End Sub


</SCRIPT>

</head>

<body style="background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.3)">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect, CSS do not use `=` for assignment. Use `:` instead, i.e.: `background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5)`

Comment: sorry that was a typo. The question still the same

Comment: Setting `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">` will bring HTA closer to present, also alpha channel is available when run in IE9 mode.

Comment: Forgot to mention, that ofcourse you will need IE9 or later installed, IE8 or former are not supporting rgba colors.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Teemu but also the `HTA` GUI's background still 100% white (I'm on W10)

Comment: Works for me in Win10 + IE11, I'm getting a pink background.

Comment: Sorry it work, but the GUI is not transparent !, Edited my question. Very strange behavior.

Comment: You mean the whole HTA window should be semi-transparent? Afaik, not possible with CSS. The only way to create such a window is to use `showModalDialog` and set `unadorned` to `yes` in options.

Comment: Can you put this as answer with a small example ? Thanks